# grouping divs with same class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, sorting, random, grouping

Just wondering if this is at all possible?

basically i have some code like this

```
<div class="stuff">content</div>
<div class="offer">content</div>
<div class="service">content</div>
<div class="service">content</div>
<div class="offer">content</div>
<div class="service">content</div>
<div class="offer">content</div>
<div class="stuff">content</div>
<div class="service">content</div>
<div class="offer">content</div>
```

This is on a desktop site with the classes in no order but what i want is when the site goes to mobile they group by class.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Cheers Andy

Comment: You should show your current code and where you are stuck with this. This question is too broad in its current state and shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they're inside a container element with id "container":

```
 var container = $("#container");    
 container.find("div").sort(function (a, b) {
     var classA = $(a).attr("class");
     var classB = $(b).attr("class");
     if (classA > classB) return 1;
     if (classA < classB) return -1;
     return 0;
 }).appendTo(container);
```

Example at: http://jsfiddle.net/JtsRz/